# Not able to config option on call back (jQuery Plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am trying to create a customizable minHeight option.

**On default**, **the minHeight variable should be equal to the object height**, BUT if a user decides to change it, they may using normal plugin config option on call back.

Below is my attempt:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.ezToggle = function(options) {

       var defaults = {

       }, 
       options = $.extend(defaults, options);

       return this.each(function() {

           defaults.minHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
           $(this).height(defaults.minHeight);

           alert(defaults.minHeight);

        });

    };
}) (jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('.foo').ezToggle({
        minHeight : 50 // Height does not change
    });
});
```

Check out the jsFiddle for a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/hCLwx/8/

Comment: so how do you want to let the user change the height?

Comment: On the call back. If you look at the bottom of my code, I am trying to set a 50 height but it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I've just realized that you are setting the element to its current height, that doesn't seem to make much sense, however I'm not 100% sure about your intentions, so I've only updated the last two examples to only set the height in case the `minHeight` option is set.

**Another update** Ok, I think I got it, you also want the option to be set to the current height in case the option wasn't set by the user. I've updated the examples again.

Check whether the option is set and if that's the case, use it over the element height. You could simply use the `||` operator:

```
return this.each(function() {

    options.minHeight = options.minHeight || $(this).outerHeight();
    $(this).height(options.minHeight);

    alert(options.minHeight);

});
```

`minHeight` will contain the `minHeight` option value in case it was set and not `0`, otherwise the element height. If you also want to accept `0` as `minHeight`, then you could for example test against `undefined`:

```
return this.each(function() {

    if(options.minHeight === undefined)
    {
        options.minHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    }

    $(this).height(options.minHeight);

    alert(options.minHeight);

});
```

Or as a third option, set a default value of `null` for the `minHeight` option and test against that:

```
var defaults = {
    minHeight: null            
}, 
options = $.extend(defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {

    if(options.minHeight === null)
    {
        options.minHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    }

    $(this).height(options.minHeight);

    alert(options.minHeight);

});
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Your first method worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I actually created my first jQuery plugin, so that was the only part I was stuck at :). Here is the  plugin on git:
https://github.com/Shivambh28/ezToggle

and demo: https://rawgithub.com/Shivambh28/ezToggle/master/demo.html